# Query to find rows with 2 consecutive months (colums) that are negative

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 table with columns representing each 12 months.  I want to find rows where there are 2 consecutive month with a negative balance.

[image]

Edit: I needed to sum all the positive columns so I used this.  If anybody knows an easier way let me know.

```
  SELECT SUM(case when Oct > 0 then Oct else 0 end) + 
         SUM(case when Nov > 0 then Nov else 0 end) +
         SUM(case when Dec > 0 then Dec else 0 end) +
         SUM(case when Jan > 0 then Jan else 0 end) +
         SUM(case when Feb > 0 then Feb else 0 end) +
         SUM(case when Mar > 0 then Mar else 0 end) +
         SUM(case when Apr > 0 then Apr else 0 end) +
         SUM(case when May > 0 then May else 0 end) +
         SUM(case when Jun > 0 then Jun else 0 end) +
         SUM(case when Jul > 0 then Jul else 0 end) +
         SUM(case when Aug > 0 then Aug else 0 end) +
         SUM(case when Sep > 0 then Sep else 0 end) as 'Sum of positive months'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it straightforward:

```
select * from tablename
where (Oct < 0 and Nov < 0) or
      (Nov < 0 and Dec < 0) or
      (Dec < 0 and Jan < 0) or
      (Jan < 0 and Feb < 0) or
      ...
```

Comment: There is also another criteria that I need.  What also counts as 2 consecutive months is if Sep from the previous year is equal to Oct.  I left out a column named account that along with FiscalYear make the rows unique.